# Avoiding long foreign key chains with FactoryGirl / rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

The short version: I have a long chain of foreign keys between tables in my database, all required / not null, and it's meaning that I have to create records in 7 different tables in factory girl, in a context where I don't need most of them. Is there any good way around this?

The long version: I'm building an app for a company that does merchandising. So, eg. Smiths Chips calls them up and says "We have a new 'Summer BBQ' flavour, and want end-of-aisle feature displays built in these 200 Coles stores across Australia". This company organises the casual workers to perform that work at each respective store.

nomenclature:
a **"Job"** is the over-arching request - eg "build end of aisle Summer BBQ displays". A job has many tasks.
a **"Task"** is the implementation of a job, in a single store, by an employee.
so, a Task belongs to an Employee, and a Store.

The long foreign key chain is: Task > Store > Suburb > Postcode > Subregion > Region > State

When testing Job and Task models, I need to create Tasks, and that means creating records in those 6 other tables, which I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: Do you need to create the tasks or can you just stub them?

Comment: When testing models it is probably the best practice to stub any other models and association. This will make your test much more resistant to changes and yet not any less valid.

Comment: Stubbing can solve the problem for some of my contexts but not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being that you have foreign keys and they are not null in your DB, my suggestion would be do disable foreign key checks for your test, and then populate your foreign key with whatever.  That way you don't need to create the related db records if they're not required for your test.

Here's a good example of how to do that in RSpec

https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/61380bb4500b4d85dd3f

And the syntax for SQLite is `PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;` / `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`

Comment: Update on this: Overall I've found it more trouble than it's worth and I think the best approach is to just not worry and keep the long foreign key chains. Your tests will be a little slower but you'll live.

Answer (score 1):

You could break the Task -> Store foreign key by using a join table. store_tasks would essentially hold just two foreign keys: one to tasks and one to stores.

So you would end up with Task <- StoreTask -> Store -> ...

That way you can test whatever you need with the Tasks independently.

The only downside is that you would be able to represent an 'orphaned' task in the database.  Which is less than ideal (goes against making it impossible to represent illegal states), but I would argue is less problematic than disabling all foreign keys in your specs as suggested by Rob.

I always test with the same database I use in production too. Databases have different coercion rules and semantics and it's possible to have tests pass in situations that would fail in production. I sometimes *like* to be able to use database specific features too: Postgres has great support for JSON, window functions, full text search etc, that I would rather embrace rather than aim for lowest common denominator. Having a different database for testing means you can't really do that.

Comment: Note: using the join table approach and enforcing that a task only belongs to one store, you would will need a unique index on the task_id on store_tasks.

Comment: I'm definitely using the same database for testing as for prod. I can see the potential headache of disabling database constraints for testing purposes, too - though at this point (3 years into the project), introducing a joins table isn't trivial either. Going to go with Robs solution for now, but got a few questions to ask on the roadtrip tomorrow!

Comment: Also, while disabling database constraints for testing seems a bad idea, so does changing the apps design, specifically so that you create less db records during tests. The motivation for my change is just to make the tests a little faster (ie, not create unneeded db records), not to make things "more testable" per se. So, changing the design solely to improve test speed doesn't quite sit right with me.

Comment: I hear you. An approach I've never tried (but would like to) is to shift domain logic to a command/transaction/operation (whatever you wanna call it) pattern and treat my ActiveRecord models as nothing but a persistence layer. Have a tests to make sure persistence works as advertised but do everything else with parameterised command objects in memory and not touch the database at all for the great majority of tests.  It's maybe not something you'd want to refactor into a 3 year old project, but for a new project.

Comment: ala Trailblazer by @apotnic?